# Store data into Array in For loop using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have two grids that use some JS fuction to move items on one grid into another, thats works fine for me. 
But my problem start when i need to get the modified grids and save data.
To do so im trying this. ( This is my function that move all the items to the other grid )

```
function AddAllItems() {
    MoveAllItems(articulosAvailable, articulosChoosen);
    UpdateButtonState();
}

var articulosEnGrilla = new Array;

function MoveAllItems(srcListBox, dstListBox) {
    srcListBox.BeginUpdate();
    var count = srcListBox.GetItemCount();
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var item = srcListBox.GetItem(i);
        dstListBox.AddItem(item.text, item.value);

        articulosEnGrilla[i] = [item.value];
        alert(articulosEnGrilla[i]);
    }         
    srcListBox.EndUpdate();
    srcListBox.ClearItems();
}
function UpdateButtonState() {
    btnMoveAllItemsToRight.SetEnabled(articulosAvailable.GetItemCount() > 0);
    btnMoveAllItemsToLeft.SetEnabled(articulosChoosen.GetItemCount() > 0);
    btnMoveSelectedItemsToRight.SetEnabled(articulosAvailable.GetSelectedItems().length > 0);
    btnMoveSelectedItemsToLeft.SetEnabled(articulosChoosen.GetSelectedItems().length > 0);
}
```

So... what im doing wrong? When i send alert its says "undefined"

My bottom

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                       @Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
                       {
                           settings.Name = "btnMoveAllItemsToRight";
                           settings.Text = "Agregar todos >>";
                           settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e) { AddAllItems(); }";
                       }).GetHtml()
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `item.value` is defined?

Comment: Yes, if its not i wolund't be able to move the item. Its a DevExpress ListBox.

Comment: Change `new Array` to `[]`. Can you try removing the `alert` and instead put a `console.log(articulosEnGrilla)` at the bottom of the function?

Comment: i change to [] and when i execute the console in Firefox says the same. "ReferenceError: reference to undefined property 0"
I add the bottom